# Angular method returning a Subscriber instead of a bool

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http

I need help with angular, I have a method that makes the verification whether the email already exists or not.

This code is responsible for this:

```
emailExists = (email) => this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/emailExists`, { 'email': email }).subscribe(response => {
    if (!response.json())
        return false

    this.handleError("Email already exists!")
    return true
}, error => this.handleError(error.json()))
```

This is who calls the method:

```
const emailValid = (auth) => 
control => {
    var a = auth.emailExists(control.value)
    var b = (/^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/).test(control.value)

    if (!a && b)
        return null
    else
        return { invalidEmail: true }
}
```

It is noticeable that the code responsible for it returns true or false depending on the originality of the email, but who is calling this method is getting a Subscriber, where am I wrong?

Imagem do retorno:
[image: Image of what its being returned]

Any additional information I will be making available.

EDIT: I couldn't get the answer in the linked duplicate, i've tried everything of that duplicate, nothing worked...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: My problem its not how to return the response, its why a Subscriber its the return...

Comment: The why is that is what angular returns from an HTTP call. The fix is contained in the linked duplicate.

Comment: i removed my answer because i misread your question. but the reason the subscribe is being returned is because your emailExists Method returns an observable and the reason that is happening is because Angulars HTTP Post method returns an observable.

Comment: this should not return an observable and instead call the http.post method

emailExists = (email) => {this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/emailExists`, { 'email': email }).subscribe(response => {
    if (!response.json())
        return false

    this.handleError("Email already exists!")
    return true
}, error => this.handleError(error.json()))}

Comment: i didn't understand the last comment

Comment: @MolikMiah That still won't set `emailExists` to a Boolean value.

Comment: @VictorHugoSchmidt You need to show how you applied the answers in the duplicate. It may be that you are misunderstanding how to apply them in your case. Basically, you will not be able to set `var a = auth.emailExists()` and have it be a Boolean. You have to do it asynchronously.

Comment: Using async/await? Already done that, [link](https://i.imgur.com/N7UrehX.png)

Answer (score 0):

> Modify the structure as mentioned using comments

```
var emailExists = (email) => {    // Keep the rest of the code within this block
  let res: boolean;               // Response that you are expecting

    this.http.post(`${this.BASE_URL}/emailExists`, {
        'email': email
    }).subscribe(response => {
        if (!response.json()) {
            res = false;                           // Assign Value
            return;
        }

        this.handleError("Email already exists!")
        res = true;                                // Assign Value
        }), error => this.handleError(error.json());

    return res;                   // Return the response, instead of Subscriber
};
```